# sharedpreferences is not working android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a simple Android app using Kotlin. I am a beginner of Kotlin Andoid. I don't how to use it, what I tried so far is mentioned below. If I enter the name it should show on the another activity using `SharedPreferences`.

**MainActivity**

```
val userName = findViewById(R.id.ed1) as EditText
val b1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1) as Button

b1.setOnClickListener {
    val editor = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("name", userName.toString())
    editor.apply()
    val intent = Intent(this,Main2Activity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("name", userName.toString())
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**MainActivity2**

```
val userName = getSharedPreferences("name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("name", "")
txt1.setText(userName)
```

Nothing is being displayed in `txt1`.

Comment: Do you have any text in your userName edittext when click b1 button?

Comment: yes sir ................

Comment: that text i have to pass in the another activity as SharedPreferences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting your edittext as string.
You should put text from the edittext and then save it to shared preference.
So use-

```
editor.putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
```

Instead of-

```
editor.putString("name", userName.toString())
```